# LINQ C# - Writing a query to display data in a pivot style

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am new to C# LINQ, and I am not sure how to write the following query. I have the following table in the database.

- > **Product**
  >
  > - ProductID
  > - Name
  > - ManufacturerID
  >
  > **Manufacturer**
  >
  > - ManufacturerID
  > - Name

Each product has a Manufacturer. The requirement is that I need to display a report that will show all the manufacturers (as columns) and show the products for each manufacturer.

Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve
http://s24.postimg.org/9baxp7xw5/Capture.png)

Since this is different from how the data is stored in the table, I am unsure of how to retrieve it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work (making some assumptions):

```
var pivot = Manufacturers.Select(m => new 
    { 
        Name = m.Name, 
        Products = Products
            .Where(p => p.ManufacturerId == m.ManufacturerId)
            .Select(p => p.Name)
            .ToList()
    });
```